# Python + Paramiko + Error: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Tags: python, linux, sudo, paramiko

I have verified the existing thread but unable to get the exact reason and resolution of this problem.

PROBLEM: 'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified'
When code is as follows:

```
str_command_to_exec += str(each_cmd).strip() + "\n"
# Now execute the command
stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command('sudo -S ls')
```

Below are the possible solutions that I have applied but still no progress.

1. Sol: Append the Password to command.
   'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified. bash: line 1: : command not found'
2. Sol2: stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command,  get_pty=True)
   More than 30 seconds still no idea whether control passed from exec_command(...).
3. Sol3: self.client.get_pty()
   Unable to setup the connection.
4. Sol4:

   stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command('sudo -S ls')
   stdin.write('\n')
   stdin.flush()
   time.sleep(2)

Unable to do the same for sudo command 'stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command('sudo -S info')' cause the same PROBLEM.

Can someone please point me if there is any solution to handle Sudo commands or workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am able to get the solution for this problem.**

I have used send(..) instead of execute_command(...).

**SETUP:**

```
self.client = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.client.AutoAddPolicy())
self.client.connect(hostname=self.str_host_name, port=22,
                    username=self.str_user_name, password=self.str_user_pass)
self.transport = paramiko.Transport(self.str_host_name, 22)
self.transport.connect(username=self.str_user_name, password=self.str_user_pass)
```

**EXECUTION:**

```
if self.shell:
    self.shell.send(str_sudo_command + "\n")

    if self.shell is not None:
    time.sleep(2)
    self.str_sudo_command_result += str(self.shell.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))
    self.str_sudo_command_result = str(self.str_sudo_command_result).strip()
    self.str_sudo_command_result = self.str_sudo_command_result.splitlines()
    if len(self.str_sudo_command_result) > 0:
        if "[sudo] password for " in self.str_sudo_command_result[-1]:
            self.str_sudo_command_result = ""
            self.shell.send(self.str_user_pass + "\n")
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            while True:
                result = str(self.str_sudo_command_result)
                result = result.splitlines()
                time.sleep(2)
                if self.str_result_end_line not in result[-1]:
                    while self.shell.recv_ready():
                        self.str_sudo_command_result += str(self.shell.recv(9999).decode('utf-8'))
            else:
                break
```

Suggestions and corrections are welcomed.